WPF TabControl showing 2 Tabs from 1 View but working different
I have a problem. I want to display 2 pages from the same view in my TabControl. Both show the same thing, but it should be possible to work differently in them. Do I need some kind of index here or how can I solve this? At the moment it shows me both identically, so if I edit something in one it is also there in the other tab.
<TabItem><views:Parameter DataContext="{Binding ParameterVM}" /></TabItem>
<TabItem><views:Parameter DataContext="{Binding ParameterVM}" /></TabItem>


You are binding both TabItems to the same view model ParameterVM, so the same underlying properties are used for both views. Having two different view models bound to DataContext will allow you to edit one without affecting the other.
